# How can I send a command to the easy-rsa docker?

Tags: php, rest, docker, mariadb, rsa

The goals is a PKI running in a docker, send commands via a REST interface, save the results in a MariaDB table (external running docker).

I found the following docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/technovilla/easy-rsa/

What I did:
Step 1: `sudo docker pull technovilla/easy-rsa`
Step 2: `sudo docker run --rm -it –--name=easy-rsa -v /home/thomas/Desktop/pki:/pki technovilla/easy-rsa:latest`
Step 3: I can see `/ #`

Question: How can I send a command to the easy-rsa docker? Can somebody explain what's written op the dockerhub page?

Regards!